# Is there a way to run a package in node_modules without specifying the full path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, ts-node

I want to run ts-node in the vs code's integrated terminal but I can only do so by specifying the full path. Is there a way to do it like i'm trying to in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Installing a package globally allows you to use the code in the package as a set of tools on your local computer.](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)

[For this use you should install ts-node GLOBALLY](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#installation):

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node
```